# Is it possible to get the HttpServletRequest object from HttpServlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I am writing a subclass of `HttpServlet`. And I want to have a method in that subclass to get the `HttpServletRequest`. However, it seems `HttpServlet` does not provide that method.

Is there any way to get round to it?

```
public class CustomServlet extends HttpServlet {
   public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
     ...
   }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you think you mean by '*the* `HttpServletRequest` object'? There is one *per request*. Not one per Servlet. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: What I mean is to add a method in CustomServlet to get the request object that the servlet is currently processing.

Comment: What makes you think there is only one at a time?

Comment: OK, I get it. Can I say it this way? Since there may be more than 1 request being processed by the same Servlet instance, it is not possible to get the request being processed?

Comment: Read the answer by @BorLaze. It is possible to get it from inside the Servlet, as it is supplied as a parameter, but otherwise, from outside the Servlet, there is no such thing as '*the* request currently being processed'. There could be none, or thousands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpServletRequest is a parameter of methods like doGet(), doPost() etc - how do you think to get it from class?

There is no way to do what you want; you can only override some methods and get HttpServletRequest inside them.